# Parsing XML from Bing Maps considering manouvertype

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, bing-maps

I have a code that retursn XML from Bing Maps, where I parse itinerery points. Interesting thing is that when I was displaying visually, I saw that Bing behaves strangely. Hence, it sometimes gives me points on straight road with no crossroads. This is a problem for my app because I receive more points than I should be.

**Question** :  I would like to eliminate points where tag : **ManouverType** is keepStraight or continueRoute.

The XML look like this

```
<ItineraryItem>
<TravelMode>Driving</TravelMode>
<TravelDistance>0.586</TravelDistance>
<TravelDuration>66</TravelDuration>
<ManeuverPoint>
<Latitude>46.086102</Latitude>
<Longitude>19.679518</Longitude>
</ManeuverPoint>
<Instruction maneuverType="EnterThenExitRoundabout">At roundabout, take 1st exit onto Ulica Bajnatska</Instruction>
<CompassDirection>west</CompassDirection>
<Detail>
<ManeuverType>EnterRoundabout</ManeuverType>
<StartPathIndex>2</StartPathIndex>
<EndPathIndex>4</EndPathIndex>
<CompassDegrees>208</CompassDegrees>
<Mode>Driving</Mode>
<PreviousEntityId>0</PreviousEntityId>
<NextEntityId>0</NextEntityId>
<RoadType>Arterial</RoadType>
</Detail>
<Detail>
<ManeuverType>ExitRoundabout</ManeuverType>
<StartPathIndex>4</StartPathIndex>
<EndPathIndex>8</EndPathIndex>
<Name>Ulica Bajnatska</Name>
<CompassDegrees>250</CompassDegrees>
<Mode>Driving</Mode>
<PreviousEntityId>0</PreviousEntityId>
<NextEntityId>0</NextEntityId>
<RoadType>Arterial</RoadType>
</Detail>
...
```

My code looks like this

```
 public List<CGeoPoint> GetItin(CGeoPair latlongpair)
    {
        string RequestText = CreateRequest(latlongpair.GeoPoint1, latlongpair.GeoPoint2);
        XmlDocument locationsResponse = MakeRequest(RequestText);

        List<CGeoPoint>  itin  = new List<CGeoPoint>();

        XmlNodeList nList = locationsResponse.GetElementsByTagName("ManeuverPoint");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nList)
        {
            decimal d1 = decimal.Parse(node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
            decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText);

            CGeoPoint ll = new CGeoPoint(d1, d2);
            itin.Add(ll);
      }
      return itin;
    }
```

This code returned me Latitude and Longitude for each ItineraryItem

Comment: Please tag the question with the language (`c#` perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this one  with following method :

```
public List<CGeoPoint> GetItin(CGeoPair latlongpair)
    {
        string RequestText = CreateRequest(latlongpair.GeoPoint1, latlongpair.GeoPoint2);

        XmlDocument locationsResponse = MakeRequest(RequestText);
        //Create namespace manager
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(locationsResponse.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("rest", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");

        //Ovde kupim sve Itinerere čak i početnu i krajnju tačku. to se kasnije izbacuje
        XmlNodeList locationElements = locationsResponse.SelectNodes("//rest:ItineraryItem", nsmgr);

        List<CGeoPoint> itin = new List<CGeoPoint>();
        foreach (XmlNode location in locationElements)
        {
            decimal lat = decimal.Parse(location.SelectSingleNode(".//rest:Latitude", nsmgr).InnerText);
            decimal longit = decimal.Parse(location.SelectSingleNode(".//rest:Longitude", nsmgr).InnerText);
            string mantype = location.SelectSingleNode(".//rest:ManeuverType", nsmgr).InnerText;
            mantype = mantype.ToUpper();

            if (mantype == "KEEPSTRAIGHT" || mantype == "CONTINUEROUTE")
            {
                //Do nothing... jump over
            }
            else
            {
                CGeoPoint ll = new CGeoPoint(lat, longit);
                itin.Add(ll);
            }
        }
        return itin;
    }
```